# how minus works

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 2 tables

```
create table table1 (tb1 number);
insert into table1 values (13);
insert into table1 values (14);
insert into table1 values (15);
insert into table1 values (16);
create table table2(tb2 number);
insert into table2 values (13);
insert into table2 values (14);
insert into table2 values (25);
insert into table2 values (26);
```

I want to output inner join values in left column and distinct right values from table 2 in right column. So it should be

```
13 25
14 26
```

I try to use minus

```
select  table1.tb1, table2.tb2  from table1 right  join table2 on table1.tb1= table2.tb2 
minus 
select  null, table2.tb2 from table1 inner join table2 on table1.tb1=table2.tb2
;
```

But instead I got

```
13 13
14 14
   25
   26
```

What can I do? Individually two selects works fine and I just wanna to do first select result minus second select result.

Comment: you can't do what you want with a `minus`. you are trying to do `(A-B) union (B-A)`.

Comment: sorry, do not understand but would try

Comment: @vkp In fact it is even more complicated since the OP wants to juxtapose two resultsets.

Comment: @ifooi: With `minus` you are eliminating whole records from a result set. Instead, you want to pair columns from different resultsets. However, you do not pair them in the base result set generated by your first query and the `minus` operator never performs such an operation either. Btw, usually a column juxtaposition doesn't make much sense since the information wrapped into a  single record is not semantically related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why

```
13 25
14 26
```

and not

```
13 26
14 25
```

?

If you are just asking for column one to be a list of rows, in numeric order, of IDs that occur in table1 and table2, and column 2 to be rows that exist in table2 but not table1 then you are looking at bringing back two unrelated lists that may have different lengths. In that case, the correlation between the values in any given row is their ranking within their individual data sets

So - it can be done like this:

```
with t1 as ( 
          select 13 a from dual
union all select 14 a from dual
union all select 15 a from dual
union all select 16 a from dual)
, t2 as (
          select 13 a from dual
union all select 14 a from dual
union all select 25 a from dual
union all select 26 a from dual)
select sub1.a  t1_a
      ,sub2.a  t2_a
from      
(-- subquery to get common values and their rankings
 select t1.a
      ,rank() over (order by t1.a) rnk
from t1 join t2 on t1.a = t2.a) sub1
full outer join 
(--subquery to get the values only in t2 and their rankings
 select t2.a
      ,rank() over (order by t2.a) rnk
from t1 right outer join t2 on t2.a = t1.a
where t1.a is null) sub2
-- join on the ranking. This is needed to avoid a cartesien product.
using (rnk)

t1_A                                   t2_a                                    
13                                     25                                     
14                                     26
```

Comment: Thanks. Still do not understand this night about minus but I like rank,

Comment: minus give the records in one query that do not occur in the second query, so I could have rewritten the second subquery to use a minus to get all t2.a where no t1.a exists, but then ordering and ranking would have required that minus to be a nested sub-select. So I used the outer join as a more appropriate construct.

Comment: I understood your construction. But still try to get why my minus not work. Minus works fine with one column but don`t with two. The column names and types are similar.

Comment: Your first column is of records where there is a match, and the second column is data that doesn't match, so how can you do a minus to include data that falls into both categories? Minus implies "not a match", so using that to get you column 1 information is not what it is meant for.